# jQuery AutoHide Function Is Hiding the Wrong DIV

Tags: jquery, html

The code below is removing the first div it finds and not the intended div.

**jQuery**

```
// Auto Remove PROMPT Notice Messages 
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[AutoHide]").each(function() {
      if (!isNaN($(this).attr("AutoHide"))) {
        eval("setTimeout(function() {jQuery('#" + this.id + "').hide();}, " + parseInt($(this).attr('AutoHide')) * 800 + ");");
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML** (or at least, the area in question looks like this)

```
<div id="notify" class="infomsg">
  <p><b>TIP:</b> Some message that should be prompted.
  <input class="close msgbutton" type="button" onclick="deleteline(this)" value="[X]" />
</div>
<div id="notify" AutoHide="5" class="successmsg">
  <p><b>SUCCESS: </b> User form processing was successful!</p>
  <input class="close msgbutton" type="button" onclick="deleteline(this)" value="[X]" />
</div>
```

Now I don't understand why the jQuery function is not removing the div with the AutoHide attribute, but is rather removing the one without (that has an id of "notify").

I figure that the culprit lies in this section of the code:

```
jQuery('#" + this.id + "').hide();
```

Comment: No wonder. ID's should be unique....

Comment: Zenith you are right, changing ID's does solve this issue. Thank you.

But allow me to ask for some insight as to what jQuery('#" + this.id + "') this line is saying? Or Can point me to where I can make this work with the AutoHide attribute alone?

Comment: if you want to use auto-hide alone, go for Gabe's answer. I would VERY VERY VERY strongly suggest you use unique ids though. It's incorrect HTML to use the same id twice, as you can see by your own example. Going against a very strict HTML standard can have unintended consequences.

Comment: @Cosmo, hide all elements if they have AutoHide? `$('[AutoHide]').hide();`. Although you can just do it in CSS instead: `[AutoHide] {
    display:none;
}`

Comment: Zenith, thank you. My question is can I use.hide() on the property or value of AutoHide? Perhaps AutoHide="yes" to hide and "no" not to hide. Thought I will be using unique div's from hence forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[AutoHide]").each(function() {
            var that = this;
            if (!isNaN($(that).attr("AutoHide"))) {
                setTimeout(function() {jQuery(that).hide();}, parseInt($(that).attr('AutoHide')) * 800 );
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I would advise not to use the same id though

Comment: Gabe, thank you. Your solution works as well. I will change my HTML code to properly accommodate the HTML standards.

Comment: And advise to not use `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

Youre using the same id twice. By rule, id's for HTML elements should be unique.

When youre using this: `jQuery('#" + this.id + "').hide();` "this.id" refers to "notify". But it's hiding the first div, because that is the first div rendered with the `id="notify"`, so that is the one it finds first.

try using unique ids:

```
<div id="info_notify" class="infomsg"><p><b>TIP:</b> Some message that should be propmted.<input class="close msgbutton" type="button" onclick="deleteline(this)" value="[X]" /></div>

<div id="success_notify" AutoHide="5" class="successmsg"><p><b>SUCCESS: </b> User form processing was successfull!</p> <input class="close msgbutton" type="button" onclick="deleteline(this)" value="[X]" /></div>
```

Comment: daybreaker, this was such an intuitive answer, clearly written. I wish that there was a way to vote the top two answers. Thank you.